# How to get row_number() in informatica?

Tags: oracle, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

How in Informatica to get the same result as we do in oracle with

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get somewhat similar functionality using the Rank transformation.

In the rank transormation, select the *GroupBy* option for the ports you would use in PARTITION BY. Specify the rank port as the port on which you would do ORDER BY. You can select only 1 rank port, however. Select *Top/Bottom* in properties for Descending/Ascending order respectively

Also, you have to manually specify the maximum number of records you are expecting in each PARTITION in the *Number of Ranks* property in Rank transformation. You can put a number that will always be greater than the count of records in any partition/group.

The RANKINDEX output from Rank Transformation will be your row number.